# Proxy at work makes https sites show as invalid cert authority, how to fix?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, ssl

The proxy at work makes https sites show up as invalid cert authority, I would prefer not to ever see that screen again, any ideas or hints on how to get around that screen, whether globally on the machine, or just in chrome, is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: show us the cert. if its self-signed, or using a rather old version of SSL, there may be no fix.

Comment: That’s right, an example would be of great help. Click on the lock icon in the address bar, select “Certificate information”, go to the “Details” tab and select “Copy to File...”. In the wizard that appears, select “Base-64 encoded X.509 (.CER)". The resulting file is plaintext which you could, for example, include directly in the question.

Comment: Be aware that your employer can see everything because they are doing this, so i'd say stay off any personal accounts like your email or amazon.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably SSL interception done to check even encrypted connections for malware. This is not uncommon in companies. In effect it does a man-in-the-middle attack and re-creates all certificates, but signed by the CA of the proxy. To get rid of this messages you have to trust this proxy CA. To do this you need to contact your system administrator to get the proper certificate and the instructions on how to import it into your browser.

Comment: I checked out the root certs on a couple of sites, they appeared to be different, I was expecting them to be the same, it made me wonder if they are "spoofing" the details of the cert, but switching out the actual crypto goodies

Comment: How did you check out the root certs? Usually the root certificate is inside the browser (which is not is in your case) and will not be sent inside the certificate chain. Maybe you could post more details about the certificate and chains you saw?

Comment: @JeffreyL.Roberts, yes, that is exactly what is happening. the question is, why does the brower reject it, and can you do anything to fix it. if its an actual legit cert for the proxy manufacturer, then you can set your browser to trust it, but if its SSL3 or Self-Signed, there will not be anything you can do. All the major browsers elected to block both of those types in the last 6-months, do to serious security flaws discovered in SSL and TLS. Thats why we need to see the cert. https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2014/10/14/the-poodle-attack-and-the-end-of-ssl-3-0/

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I will get some more details and follow up shortly

Comment: @FrankThomas I would imagine it is self signed, will be back with more deets soon

Answer (score -4):

Actually this happenes probably because your time is wrong. This is why I couldint connect, try changing your time.

Comment: Except we know the proxy is at fault because its doing a man in the middle attack.